# Mocking a function with Sinon

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocking, sinon, spy

I cant seem to find a way to do a really simple thing like the below:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="messageDetail">
        <div className="messageForm" >
          Name: <input id="senderMsgName" value={this.props.nameValue} onChange={this.props.handleNameChange}/>
          <br />
          Body: <input id="senderMsgBody" value={this.props.bodyValue} onChange={this.props.handleBodyChange}/>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

All I want to test is that the onChange function is called. how can I mock this out using sinon (bearing in mind it called on props)? I then will simulate it being called to test it.

I started with this: `const handleBodyChangeSpy = sinon.spy();`
and will expect this: `expect(handleBodyChangeSpy).to.have.not.been.called();`

just need some guidance on how to do that

Comment: Can you post your test?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ES6 and `class Component extends React.Component`. In that case you can create a spy by writing `var spy = sinon.spy(Component.prototype, "handleBodyChange")`. You can test your assertions on that spy.

More about creating spies here: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/spies/ (check under **Creating spies: sinon.spy() Method Signatures**).